# How can one open a browser: edge or chrome or firefox, to specific pixel dimensions?

Tags: windows, windows-10-desktop

I have tried the following shortcut for edge, with no success:

Shortcut Definition:

Target:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" --profile-directory=Default --window-size=800,900
```

Start in:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application"
```

The window opens ignoring the specified window size.

Comment: [Super User](https://superuser.com/) shall give you the answer. I suppose the general reason of the described behavior - already running runned processes.  Try to kill all processes before shortcut run: `taskkill /f /im msedge.exe`